# What are the best egg substitutes for different types of bakes?

Tags: baking, substitutions, vegan

I have done a variety of vegan baking and often end up 'experimenting' based on what I have on hand at the moment. I know a few egg substitute tricks include applesauce, flaxseed, or store-bought substitutes such as Vegg and Just Egg. I want to better understand when I should use which substitute for cakes, cookies, brownies, quick breads, etc.

What are the best substitutes for different types of bakes? Is there a time when applesauce is better than a flaxseed "egg"? Is there a better substitute when the goal of the egg is emulsification v structure v leavening (or a combination)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the role of the egg in the bake, but if it's for emulsification, you can usually use `aquafaba` which is the liquid product when you cook legumes.

> Due to its ability to mimic functional properties of egg whites in
> cooking, aquafaba can be used as a direct replacement for them in some
> cases, including meringues and marshmallows. It is especially suitable
> for use by people who avoid eggs, such as vegans.

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquafaba)

Comment: I was pleasantly surprised at the results the first time I used aquafaba for a meringue. Made hummus from the chickpeas and meringue from the chickpea "water". Turned out great!

Comment: Wow! I make my own hummus all the time and never knew about this other use case for the liquid. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

This link will help:  https://tyberrymuch.com/vegan-egg-substitutes/

The AU notes that "eggs are used for five main reasons in baking," and then talks about which of the 16 vegan substitutes he notes work best in which contexts.

...............

Fwiw: To bind ingredients, I prefer a chickpea-flour egg (equal parts chickpea flour and water, allowed to sit for a few minutes). Be warned: Chickpea flour tastes disgusting when it's raw, but you'll taste nothing in the baked product.

I also like chia eggs for binding; they're less adhesive than flax eggs, but they add a pleasant flavor and texture.

Comment: Welcome! Please don’t post answers where the core information requires following a link (just think how often links go bad and how useful your answer would then be). Find an instruction how to properly include information from other sources [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). For all new users taking the [tour] and browsing through the [help] is very much recommended.